# Projectile Collider colliding with triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

In the shooter game I am making, my bullets have two collision rules, one for hitting enemies and one for everything else. Code looks like this:

```
- private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
- ContactPoint contact = other.GetContact(0);
- tag = other.gameObject.tag;
- if (tag == "Enemy"){
- Debug.Log("Enemy got owned");
- other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyCont>().TakeDamage(bulletDamage);
- else {
- Debug.Log("instantiate");
- bulletDecalg = GameObject.Instantiate(bulletDecal, contact.point + contact.normal * 0.001f, Quaternion.LookRotation(contact.normal));
- Destroy(bulletDecalg, 3);
- 
- Destroy(gameObject);
-     }
```

-However, my enemies also have trigger colliders I will be using as hitboxes for their attacks. These are set to isTrigger true, but the bullets stop as if they hit a non trigger collider with no rigidbody.

I have tried to add a rigidbody to the hitbox collider and I have tried adding and removing rigidbodies and colliders on the bullet itself. Neither changed the behaviour.

Comment: The code you shared wouldn't compile due to neither the `if` block nor the method itself not having a closing bracket (not to mention all of the nonsensical hyphens). Make sure you have constructed a [mcve] to get the most prompt and helpful responses.

Comment: Check that your tag has no spaces and is the same casing etc.. one of the few failings of unity is using strings

Comment: Yeah, this is one of my first posts, my code formatting is really bad. The code compiles, there's no compiler errors there, just logic errors.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly answered this yourself in your question. You mentioned that the trigger on the collider is a trigger, so instead of using `OnCollisionEnter` you will want to use `OnTriggerEnter()`.

I'm not sure if there is more missing, but here's something I put together to maybe help get you closer:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
   tag = other.tag;
   if (tag == "Enemy"){
     Debug.Log("Enemy got owned");
     other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyCont>().TakeDamage(bulletDamage);
   else {
     Debug.Log("instantiate");
     bulletDecalg = GameObject.Instantiate(bulletDecal, contact.point + contact.normal * 0.001f, Quaternion.LookRotation(contact.normal));
     Destroy(bulletDecalg, 3);
}
```

Do double check and make sure your enemy has the tag `Enemy` with capital `E`.